# Azure: Cannot remove orphaned container group

Tags: azure

I'm being charged for an azure resource with the type "Container Group" that is part of a resource group (RG-TEST) that no longer exists.

It is nowhere to be found in the portal outside of cost management. I have even tried re-creating the RG and deleting it, but it still shows up on my bill.

[image: azure cost mgmt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Azure Support to report this.